# Rails where.not skips some records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord, associations

I try to fetch all videos except the ones with categories [20,21,22]

**this is my query**

```
@cc = Video.joins(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: [20,21,22]})
```

but when I do `@cc.find(113).categories` I get this

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
[#<Category id: 21, title: "music">, #<Category id: 22, title: "movies">,
#<Category id: 28, title: "collage">]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a wrong query.
Try with:

```
Video.where.not(id: Video.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: [20,21,22]}).pluck(:id))
```

Comment: How many queries does it generate? I guess just one. If it generates two queries then replace `pluck(:id)` with `select(:id)`.

Comment: that does the trick :) I jus kind of hopped there would be some more "elegant" way of writing this query, but I guess it really doesn't matter when the performance is good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array = [21,22,23]
@cc = Video.joins(:categories).where("category.id not in (?)", array)
```

**EDIT**

Think I spot the problem. Suppose your `Video` model is in a `has_many` relationship with `Category`. So you should do:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :excluded, -> (array) { where("id not in (?)", array) }, class_name: 'Category'
end
```

And you call it like that:

```
Video.find(113).excluded([21,22,23])
```

Comment: what if you replace `in` with `any`?

Comment: thank you for your edit, but this does something else than I desired. But Thank you for this I learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@cc = Video.includes(:categories).references(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: [20,21,22]})
```

Refer,
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot

Comment: still the same. I can still find the video with id 113 in the retrieved collection which has these wrong categories

Comment: can u show me the query fired and also the @cc.categories

Comment: this is query fired 

SELECT "videos"."id" AS t0_r0, "videos"."id_string" AS t0_r1, "videos"."title" AS t0_r2, "videos"."duration" AS t0_r3, "videos"."thumbnail" AS t0_r4, "videos"."rating" AS t0_r5, "videos"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "videos"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "categories"."id" AS t1_r0, "categories"."title" AS t1_r1 FROM "videos" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories_videos" ON "categories_videos"."video_id" = "videos"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_videos"."category_id" WHERE ("categories"."id" NOT IN (20, 21, 22))

Comment: @cc.categories

NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for #<Video::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbb4d9e0358>